# Connected spaces where every dense set is large

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $\kappa >\aleph_0$ be a cardinal. Is there a connected space $(X,\tau)$ with $|X| = \kappa$ such that for every [dense set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) $D\subseteq X$ we have $|D|=|X|$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Take any countable connected Hausdorff space $C$, fix any point $c\in C$, and consider the quotient space $X=C\times \kappa/ \{c\}\times \kappa$. Here the cardinal $\kappa$ is endowed with the discrete topology.

It is easy to see that the space $X$ is connected and Hausdorff and each dense subset of $X$ has cardinality $|\kappa|$.